# Should jmeter master start after 1/2 minutes of server started when running tests in non gui mode (master and slave)

Tags: jmeter

Bamboo-jmeter task: Should time gap there before starting the jmeter master/slave. We have created bamboo task (SSH task1-with slave host, SSHtask2-with 2nd slave host, SSH task3-with master host and run commands). When first time the the task getting an error remote engine is not able to configured whereas able to telnet the hosts, also jmeter-server is already started. 
However when disable SSHtask1 and task2 for the 2nd time run, it is able to run successfully and getting results also.
Should jmeter master start after 1/2 minutes of server started? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Able to overcome the problem by adding sleep time of 120 seconds after running the jmeter-server before starting the jmeter master.